# on_message disables all my command even with bot.process bot.process_commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot and I am trying to make a feature if you say **"hi"** the bot will say **"hi"** back. But using on_message all my other commands get disabled.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if message.content == "hi":
      await message.channel.send('hi')
    await bot.process_commands(ctx)
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix this error.

Comment: Since when does `on_message` take two arguments? Where did you find that? It takes one, `message`, not `ctx`.

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` takes a single argument `message` and does not take `ctx` parameter and you need to pass `message` in `bot.process_commands()`

So it should look like this :

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
      await message.channel.send('hi')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Which would result in :
[image]

If you do not intend this type of 'recursive' behavior from your bot then adding a check to see if the bot is triggering to its own message would help :

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send("hi")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Also, you could do something like this :

```py
@bot.listen("on_message")
async def check_if_contains(msg):
    if msg.author == bot.user:
        return
    if msg.content == "Hi":
        await msg.channel.send("Hello there!")
```

Which would eliminate the need to load commands seperately.

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` takes only one argument - `message`. You should also use `message` instead of `ctx` in `process_commands()` and if you are using the `client` variable then use `client.process_commands()` not `bot.process_commands()`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send('hi')
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

And to avoid the bot taking messages from itself which would result in sending "hi" over and over again use this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send('hi')
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

***You also have to enable [`intents.messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents%20message#discord.Intents.messages)!***